# putting Store procedure columns in Razor code

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, model-view-controller, linq-to-sql

i am calling store procedure from MVC, which returns single record only.

SP contains:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMonthlyReport] @emplID INT = NULL,
    @month VARCHAR(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (@emplID IS NOT NULL AND @month IS NOT NULL) --If Block begins
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM MonthlyRecord
        WHERE Month = @month AND EmplID = @emplID
    END --If block ends
    ELSE --Else block begins
    BEGIN
        RETURN 0
    END --Else block ends
END
```

now it is selecting, empID, Overtime, Month, TotalDuration from MonthlyRecord View,

What i want to do is to put these fields in custom template e.g. HTML TABLE or List, like :

```
<table style="width:300px">
<tr>
<td>Employee ID</td>
<td>Month</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>@empID</td>
<td>@Month</td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

something dynamic.

MVC Code:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Generated_PaySlip(int? emplID, String month) 
{
IEnumerable<GetMonthlyReportResult> PaySlip = DataContext.GetMonthlyReport(emplID, month).ToList();
return View(PaySlip);
}
```

View:

```
@using EmployeeAttendance_app.Models

<h2>Employee Pay Slip</h2>

<table style="width:300px">
<tr>
<td>Employee ID</td>
<td>Month</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>@empID</td>
<td>@Month</td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close, but you need to tell the Razor view what model you're using. 
Revise your Razor code as such:

```
@model GetMonthlyReportResult
@using EmployeeAttendance_app.Models

<h2>Employee Pay Slip</h2>

<table style="width:300px">
<tr>
<td>Employee ID</td>
<td>Month</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>@Model.empID</td>
<td>@Model.Month</td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

Then you can use `Model` as the variable in the Razor view to access the properties.

**update**

I just noticed that you're returning an `IEnumerable`. Somewhere you need to convert that into a single item. Since you are only expecting to see one return item, I think it would be easier to do that in the controller.

```
public ActionResult Generated_PaySlip(int? emplID, String month) 
{
    IEnumerable<GetMonthlyReportResult> PaySlip = DataContext.GetMonthlyReport(emplID, month).ToList();
    return View(PaySlip.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

**update**

You can leave the controller as is in your example and do it in the Razor view like so:

```
@model IEnumerable<GetMonthlyReportResult>
@using EmployeeAttendance_app.Models

@{
    var item = Model.FirstOrDefault();
}

<h2>Employee Pay Slip</h2>

<table style="width:300px">
<tr>
<td>Employee ID</td>
<td>Month</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>@item.empID</td>
<td>@item.Month</td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

But again, since you're only expecting one item, there is no need to add that logic to the Razor view. Best, I think, to leave that kind of stuff to the controller whenever possible.

Comment: It's funny because the information that he is trying to put there are the parameters.

Comment: @ivowiblo ha ha good catch. I had assumed the example was a simple one, and the OP would end up extending the table to include the other data from the model.

Comment: @ivowiblo and Jwatts: if you geniuses would tell me that what you guys are discussing ? am i doing something wrong ? care to share ?

Comment: Have you tried what @jwatts1980 proposed? It looks right.

Comment: yeah it works but i am confused about one thing like difference between "using EmployeeAttendance_app.Models"
        and "model GetMonthlyReportResult"............ why not to use one ?

Comment: In a model driven framework like MVC, the Razor needs to know what kind of data to expect. `model` tells the Razor view what data type it is expecting to receive. `using` is just like anywhere else: it just brings a library for shorthand referencing. You can put code into code blocks like `@{  }` or `@(  )` as in my second example, so a `using` statement will help with that.

Comment: Btw, if my answer was correct or helped you out, please mark it as such. Thanks!